# How do I use (instancetype)arrayWithObjects:(id)?

Tags: ios, global, instancetype

I am trying to use this iOS function

- +(instancetype)arrayWithObjects:(id)

I believe I passed an array into it, but I cannot figure out how to access that array and I do not understand HOW to use this. I have spent several hours trying to figure it out ... PLEASE help me!

```
+ (instancetype)arrayWithObjects:(id)[@"Starcraft", @"League of Legends", @"Starcraft 2", @"World of Warcraft",
@"The Sims", @"Icewind Dale", @"Shadowbane", @"Grand Theft Auto 3", @"Pac Man", @"Astroids",
@"Grand Theft Auto 4", @"Grand Theft Auto 5", @"MineCraft", @"Mass Effect", @"Mass Effect 2",
@"Mass Effect 3", @"Dragon Age", @"The Sims 2", @"The Sims 3", @"Rockband", @"Rockband 2",
@"Rockband 3", @"Dragon Age 2", @"The Witcher", @"The Witcher 2", @"Plants vs Zombies",
nil]
{
    return [[[self class] alloc] init];
}
```

Comment: do you want to initialize an array?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. You just want to build an array of objects?

Comment: I want to learn how to use this global function, as I cannot figure out how to use it ... how to properly make arrays with it and how to call upon or interact with the array it creates. Shouldn't this function be an array factory?

Comment: The function is fine, but you are recreating it here instead of using it. Take out the { } part, that is only needed when you define a function. Apple already defined it for you, it will return an array if you just do NSArray arrayWith blah...

Like how this guy's question uses it, similar to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970412/initialize-array-of-objects-using-nsarray but without "recreating" the inner part.

Comment: ok, I think I have found the answer to my question. It ends up "+(instancetype)arrayWithObjects:(id)" is the under the hood function that is already there. I thought I was making a new function that I was trying to then utilize.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you really want if you want an entire array of objects instead of an array with a single array in it which is what you had originally.

```
NSArray* array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Starcraft", @"League of Legends", @"Starcraft 2", @"World of Warcraft",
@"The Sims", @"Icewind Dale", @"Shadowbane", @"Grand Theft Auto 3", @"Pac Man", @"Astroids",
@"Grand Theft Auto 4", @"Grand Theft Auto 5", @"MineCraft", @"Mass Effect", @"Mass Effect 2",
@"Mass Effect 3", @"Dragon Age", @"The Sims 2", @"The Sims 3", @"Rockband", @"Rockband 2",
@"Rockband 3", @"Dragon Age 2", @"The Witcher", @"The Witcher 2", @"Plants vs Zombies",
nil];
```

It creates an NSArray at runtime of the given strings ending in nil to indicate the end.

Comment: Thank you very much ahwulf, but, No. I am specifically trying to learn how to use this global method, array factory, of +(instancetype)arrayWithObjects:(id)

Comment: The answer provided is using this exact method to create an NSArray object containing the NSString objects which you specified.  This answer is exactly correct.  You don't want to be overriding this method, you just want to be using/calling on it to create NSArray objects.

Comment: Actually yes, the line here does use the global method. What you might not see is that it is global because it returns into an instance, but I assure you it is global. Here's an example of global [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"object", nil], an instance variable would be called on the instance, as in a "thing" would be after the open bracket "[" like this, [myArray sort], which may or may not return something, but it is "instance" because it's not called on the NSArray factory/blueprint.

Comment: Another issue is instancetype, which is a new keyword iOS added to confuse us, actually I have to look it up every time I use it since I still code old mem-managed. You will want to ensure you find any docs on instanceType if it is new

Comment: When I make an array like this, is it a normal array, it is not using the global method because I already did it. I commented out the global code and it works fine. I am trying to understand how to use the global code. The global code is not even used if I just manually make the array.

Comment: I did not understand that the global function already exists under the hood. I thought I was doing something new and trying to use it. *sigh* the Apple doc always mess me up. Hopefully one day I will be able to translate them into something useful.